# Find and delete duplicates only if two fields have matching data Ms Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I want to create a query that would find and delete duplicates only if two fields have matching data. Not meaning those two fields match exactly, like field A and field B both have "unprocessed" but in a sense that two records in the table have "1234" in field A AND "unprocessed" in field B then that whole row of record should be deleted and only the oldest record (the one clearly closer to the column headings) will stay in the table.

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As always, be sure to take a backup of your access database before you do any of this deleting.

NOTE, you can create these queries by switching to "SQL" view on the query. (rather than the default 'Design' view).

Step 1 - Identify the duplicate data.  Create a make table group by query that groups by the 2 fields that you want to check for duplicates on, and then take a count and a max.  Filter to show only records that have a count > 1. Save this as "Query1".  This will create a temporary table called TEMP_DeleteThese.

```
SELECT Table1.CaseID, Table1.Status, 
        Count(Table1.ID) AS CountOfID, 
        Max(Table1.ID) AS MaxOfID 
INTO TEMP_DeleteThese
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.CaseID, Table1.Status
HAVING (((Count(Table1.ID))>1));
```

Step 2 - Create a delete query based upon TEMP_DeleteThese and a join back to the original Table, through the "Max ID" field, which will be the newest duplicate record.

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW Table1.*
FROM TEMP_DeleteThese INNER JOIN Table1 ON TEMP_DeleteThese.MaxOfID = Table1.ID;
```

Run both the make table and delete queries as many times as needed to delete all duplicates.

I made an assumption here that you have a primary key (in this case "Table1.ID") that is auto numbered starting with low numbers, and counting to higher.

Comment: I appreciate this great explanation, but I don't know how to create anything you just said. If it was written in SQL I would know where to put my table and field names, but actually building it from scratch I can't do. I'm fairly new to Access and only know how to build simple queries :(

Comment: Is this a one time exercise to remove duplicates, or will you need to have a repeatable process in place?  If you edit your question with more specific field names, I can attempt to frame up the SQL.

Comment: This will definitely be repeatable. Field "caseid" and Field "status" are the two fields are am referring to. Thank you.